# Statsd client not sending all event metrics

Tags: influxdb, statsd, telegraf

I am using https://github.com/tim-group/java-statsd-client statsd client in my java project to send metrics accros my influxdb using telegraf and statsd. I see there are some data points that are missed. I have 4 threads that are running in my program which are continuously sending metrics over 2 sec.

Like if I send a event whose gauge is 1000, 70 times I am just shown 40k in my influxdb as aggregation. I have added error handler as well to print error, but there is no error that is printed. Neither from the program nor at the telegraf side.

Answer (score 0):

Because StatsD use udp protocol, packets will probably be lost when transmit from client to server. And also, client can't be aware of loss because it just send packets to network irresponsibly.

Since then, the problem is hard to explain and solve if nothing about your server or your client are given.